# Запись данных из двух отдельных потоков в один файл

Tags: c++, winapi, потоки-данных

Как реализовать запись данных из двух отдельных потоков в один файл? Мне кажется что проще с использовать WinAPI, но не имею представления как это сделать

Comment: С ходу. Очередь в мьютексом. 2 потока передают, 1 читает. Или 2 потока пишут (захват мьютекса для записи). Куча вариантов.

Comment: @MrBin - тогда уж не мьютекс, а критическая секция. Мьютекс это инструмент синхронизации процессов, для потоков одного процесса он избыточен.

Comment: @freim, Тут либо c++, либо WinAPI. В c++ нет критических секций, только mutex.